# Completeness relation of spin matrices

Tags: conformal-field-theory, spinors, clifford-algebra

I was reading Hugh Osborne's notes on Conformal Field theory and came across a completeness relation which seems easy to prove but I am unable to do it.

${(s_{\mu\nu})}_{\alpha}^{\beta}{(s^{\mu\nu})}_{\gamma}^{\delta}=\frac{1}{2}({\gamma_{\mu})}^{\beta}_{\alpha}({\gamma^{\mu})}^{\delta}_{\gamma}={\delta_{\alpha}^{\delta}}{\delta_{\gamma}^{\beta}}-\frac{1}{2}{\delta}_{\alpha}^{\beta}{\delta}_{\gamma}^{\delta}$,

where the spin matrices $s_{\mu\nu}$ are defined by

$s_{\mu\nu}$=$\frac{-1}{2}([{\gamma}_{\mu},{\gamma}_{\nu}])$

It would be highly helpful if someone can just sketch the proof.

Comment: Which of the two equalities do you have trouble proving? Both of them?

Comment: First equality is specific for d=3 I suppose and I proved it. But in the second equality I am getting a factor of 4 wrong.

Comment: @M.Jo second relation is the definition of spin matrix. I have problem with first relation.